# Scale div elements to window size

Tags: css, html

I'm currently working on the [skeleton layout](http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/zRrxf/) for a new web application but have encountered a few problems most noticeably with CSS layouts and DIV.

1) Boxes 1 and 2 (column 1) do not line up with 3 (column 2) and 4 (column 3). How can I straighten this up?

2) I really like how the the interface [here](http://biblia.com/books/esv) which automatically resizes when minimised to a certain size and scales up when the window is maximised. I've been trying to implement this into my layout but can't. It is unfortunate how the footer "sticks out". I would like everything to fit onto one page. How do I go about achieving this as in the abovementioned website?

Many thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<!--  
============================================
LOGO
============================================
-->

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>

<!--   
============================================
NAVBAR
============================================
-->   

<div id="header">
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="#">link 2</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="#">link 3</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="#">link 4</a>
</div>

  <div style="clear: both;"></div>

<!--  
============================================
NAVIGATION & CONTACTS
============================================
-->

<div class="column" id="first-column">
    <div class="window" id="window-1">1</div>
    <div class="window" id="window-2">2</div>
</div>

<!--   
============================================
MAIN CONTENT
============================================
-->

<div class="column" id="second-column">
    <div class="window" id="window-3">3</div>
</div>

<!--
============================================
CHAT
============================================
-->

<div class="column" id="third-column">
    <div class="window" id="window-4">4</div>
</div>

<!--  
============================================
FOOTER
============================================
-->

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
/*
============================================
GENERAL
============================================
*/

body, html{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

/*
============================================
LAYOUT SKELETON
============================================
*/

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1212px;
    min-height: 540px;
    min-width: 784px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

#header{
    text-align:right;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#first-column{
    width: 20%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}

#second-column{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#third-column{
    width: 25%;
}

.window{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid #CECECE;
    width:100%;
}

#window-1{
    height:50%;
}

#window-2{
    margin-top:10px;
    height:50%;
}

#window-3{
    height: 100%;
}

#window-4{
    height:100%;
}

.column{
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

​

Comment: Links can become stale please include the code in the question also.

Answer (score 1):

1) You have 2 divs in column 1 at 50% height so 2 sets of margins. You have 1 div in column 2 so just 1 set of margin, so naturally column 1 will be longer by the margin you use. Best I can offer to fix it is to add a padding of 10px to the bottom. This should catch up on the first columns margins.

2) Add a min and a max width, then set the width to a %. Say 100px min, 300px max and 50% width. As long as the screen is 200px to 600px wide it will be 50%, otherwise it will be at the specified limitations

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you include an example in my code please? http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/zRrxf/

Comment: I'm at work so don't have enough time to fix no2 for you, maybe later.

But for number 1, just add `padding-bottom: 12px;` to #window-3

Comment: Thanks I'm heading off to work now myself. Hope to catch up with you later. I will wait for your edits when you have the time :-)